# What is the use of done() callback here?

Tags: node.js

```
`passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
  clientID: config.google.clientID,
  clientSecret: config.google.clientSecret,
  callbackURL: config.google.callbackURL,
  passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
      return done(null, profile);
    });
  }
));`
```

I have used Google authentication using Passport in NodeJS. What is the significance of done() callback here, and why do we give null as an argument? I haven`t got any proper explanation. At least I should know why I am using the same.

Comment: `done` is calling the next middleware in the pipeline.  By convention, the first argument is for errors.  Since there are no errors you are passing `null`.

Comment: can I use next() in place of done()? Like we use in other middleware?

Comment: you can name the parameter whatever you'd like.  But if the docs for `GoogleStrategy` call it `done`, then you risk confusing developers that read the code later.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @DavinTryon